# Model observers : restored() and restoring()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to restore comments attached to a post ***after*** the post is restored.

This fails :

```php
public function restored(Post $post)
{
    $post->comments()
        ->onlyTrashed()->where('deleted_at', '>=', $post->deleted_at)
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($comment) {
            $comment->restore();
        });
}
```

This works:

```php
public function restoring(Post $post)
{
    $post->comments()
        ->onlyTrashed()->where('deleted_at', '>=', $post->deleted_at)
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($comment) {
            $comment->restore();
        });
}
```

Difference is: `restoring()` instead of `restored()`.

The following condition : `where('deleted_at', '>=', $post->deleted_at)` is here because I do not want to restore comments that were soft-deleted before the post was deleted. In other words, I do not want to restore comments that were soft-deleted by moderators. I want to restore the comments that were soft-deleted the very moment I soft-deleted the post.

Reason why it fails: I believe it fails with `restored()` because `$post->deleted_at` becomes `null` so I cannot use it in my `where(...)` condition anymore.

Question: how do I hold the previous value of `$post->deleted_at`, right before it was restored? I tried playing with `getDirty()` and `getChanges()` but these did not help, they hold no track of previous value in the observer.

I also tried the following :

```php
public function restoring(Post $post)
{
    $this->deleted_at = $post->deleted_at;
}
```

thinking it would allow me to 'persist' the value of `$post->deleted_at` and be able to use it in my `restored()` method. But no.

I noticed `restored()` only restores the first comment. It's like once a comment is restored, within a kind of loop, then `$post->deleted_at` because `null` (obviously, since it's `restored` and not `restoring`) so it cannot continue restoring the other comments in the Collection. I think it throws the error because I guess the loop is then trying to do like `where('deleted_at', '>=', null)` (notice the ```null``)`.
Sure enough, this does works :

```
public function restored(Post $post)
{
    $post->comments()
        ->onlyTrashed()
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($comment) {
            $comment->restore();
        });
}
```

(please note this is `restored()` but I had to get rid of my `where(...)`, but I DO need that `where(...)` condition).

Basically and ***TL;DR*** : how can I get the 'old' value of `$post->deleted_at` (the value right before it was restored), within my `public function restoring(Post $post) { }`

Comment: `getChanges` should have what was changed in it after `save` which `restore` calls, unless its pulling a new instance of the same model (i believe) .. the changes are synced in `performUpdate`

Comment: sadly it invokes a new instance. ```getChanges``` does not hold any interesting data for me, as stated on the first post. Moreover, nothing ìnteresting either if I run ```dd($post);``` within ```restored()```. The ```deleted_at``` info is completely lost. The SoftDeletes trait performs ```$this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = null;``` within the ```restore()``` method, right before ```$this->fireModelEvent('restored', false);```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal method, but it seems to work in some quick tests.  You can also set up getter and setter methods in your Post model if you prefer to interact with the property in that way.

**Post.php**

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    // add a custom property with a unique name
    // this will prevent the data from being assigned as an attribute
    public $temp_deleted_at;

    // ...
}
```

**PostObserver.php**

```php
public function restoring(Post $post)
{
    // store to custom property
    $post->temp_deleted_at = $post->deleted_at;
}

public function restored(Post $post)
{
    // retrieve from custom property for query
    $post->comments()
        ->onlyTrashed()->where('deleted_at', '>=', $post->temp_deleted_at)
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($comment) {
            $comment->restore();
        });
}
```

Comment: That won't work because restoring and restored are 2 different instances. That does work with static calls though.

Comment: Can you edit like the following : ```public function restoring(Post $post)
    {
        static::$deleted_at = $post->deleted_at;
    }``` and ```private static $deleted_at = null;``` so that I can accept your answer. This passes my phpunit tests.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm satisfied that the code above does in fact work. I have run it again just to be certain. I'm not comfortable taking credit for a solution that is significantly different from what I posted. Please, feel free to answer your own question if you feel your solution is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$model->getOriginal('deleted_at')` to retrieve the original value of `deleted_at` in your `restored()` listener.